# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method App\App::run() in Slim-4 php and php-di

Tags: php, slim, php-di, slim-4

While working with Slim and PHP-DI, got a warning saying

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method App\App::run()`

The code is as follows:

```
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new \DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge;
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of PHP-DI, there are some changes

`DI\Bridge\Slim\App` has changed to `DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge`. So if you are using `use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DiBridge;` may not work. Instead try `use DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge as DiBridge;`

There is no `$app->run()` method defined in PHP-DI Bridge class, hence its undefined. Instead use `$app->create()` method.

**Note**

In order to use `create()` method on `$app`, make sure you have slim/psr7 installed, otherwise you may see a bloody red warning. If you dont have slim/psr7 installed use the following command to get it installed

`composer require slim/psr7`

So after making sure slim/psr7 is there, code must look as follows

```
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
$app = new \DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge;
$app->create();
```